# Issues in fetching API data PHP

Tags: php, api

I was trying to fetch some data using the GeoName API but I am having difficulties in retrieving it as I might have missed something. I am still quite new to PHP so I am wondering where my mistake is.

I would like to use the info stored in my $_REQUEST array which should be posted by my inputs in my HTML, however I believe there is some sort of mistake/oversight that prevents me to fetch the data from the API.

## php file

```
<?php

$url =
    'http://api.geonames.org/weatherJSON?north=' .
    $_REQUEST['North'] .
    '&south=' .
    $_REQUEST['South'] .
    '&east=' .
    $_REQUEST['East'] .
    '&west=' .
    $_REQUEST['West'] .
    '&username=kyleghilotti';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

//echo $_REQUEST['South'] . 'Look here...';
//echo $data . 'Hello';
curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($data, true);

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

## HTML FILE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/index.css">
    <title>Task | GeoNames</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id=”preloader”></div>
    
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>API Name</td>
            <td>API Description</td>
            <td>Go</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Weather By coordinates</td>
            <td>Weather</td>
            <td><button id="coordinates">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name2</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><button>Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name3</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><button>Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
            <label for="North">North</label>
            <input name="North" type="number" id="North" formaction="./php/api.php"/>
            <label for="South">South</label>
            <input name="South" type="number" id="South" formaction="./php/api.php"/>
            <label for="East">East</label>
            <input name="East" type="number" id="East" formaction="./php/api.php"/>
            <label for="West">West</label>
            <input name="West" type="number" id="West" formaction="./php/api.php"/>
    </table>

    <div>
        <span id="clouds"></span>
        <span id="temperature"></span>
        <span id="station"></span>
    </div>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any further help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Do your form inputs work without any form tags? What is in `$_REQUEST` when you `var_dump()` it at the start of your PHP code?

Comment: _"which should be posted by my inputs in my HTML"_ - those are not even part of a _form_, so nothing gets send _anywhere_ here. (Unless you had additional JavaScript to read the field values and make the request to the server ...?)

Comment: And just sticking label and input into a table like that, is invalid HTML to begin with. The table must contain table rows, which in turn contain table cells.

Comment: @droopsnoot the error is : syntax error, unexpected variable "$url"

Comment: Please post the entire error message in the question and itenify in the code the line it is referring too.

Comment: Your passing in the URL on the curl_init . CURLOPT_URL is set when you passed it in per the manual [curl_init](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Comment: I haven't seen any problems with the code posted so far. This syntax error, even though it points to $url, may be due to a problem in previous code.

Comment: Error: Invalid argument    prepareInjection.js:640:17 @Jason K

Comment: That's java script. You haven't posted any of that.